# Using the click package: Making an option be a choice of `int`

Tags: python, click

I'm trying to make a `click.option` be a choice between the numbers `0`, `1` and `2`. I tried this:

```
@click.Option('--verbosity', default=1, type=click.Choice([0, 1, 2]))
def f():
    # ...
    pass
```

But I get the exception `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`. I guess `click` expects only strings in `click.Choice`. Any way to get it to accept ints? I know I can convert to int manually after it's received, but if there's an idiomatic way to receive an `int` choice, that'll be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `IntRange(min=0, max=2)`:

> `class click.IntRange(min=None, max=None, clamp=False)`
>
> A parameter
>   that works similar to click.INT but restricts the value to fit into a
>   range. The default behavior is to fail if the value falls outside the
>   range, but it can also be silently clamped between the two edges.

[From the docs.](http://click.pocoo.org/5/api/#click.IntRange)